# unable to select all checkboxes in tree using angular2-tree on init

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Objective : i have a button named "feed data" so when ever i click it the data will be loaded i mean the tree with checkboxes here my requirement is when ever i click it along with data all the check boxes have to be checked on init i tried using

```
 this.treeComp.treeModel.doForAll((node: TreeNode) => node.setIsSelected(true));
```

but it is not working below is my code

```
 click(tree: TreeModel) {

    this.arrayData = [];

    let result: any = {};
    let rs = [];

    console.log(tree.selectedLeafNodeIds);





    Object.keys(tree.selectedLeafNodeIds).forEach(x => {


      let node: TreeNode = tree.getNodeById(x);
      // console.log(node);


      if (node.isSelected) {

        if (node.parent.data.name) //if the node has parent
        {
          rs.push(node.parent.data.name + '.' + node.data.name);
          if (!result[node.parent.data.name]) //If the parent is not in the object
            result[node.parent.data.name] = {} //create
          result[node.parent.data.name][node.data.name] = true;

        }
        else {
          if (!result[node.data.name]) //If the node is not in the object
            result[node.data.name] = {} //create
          rs.push(node.data.name);
        }


      }
    })
    this.arrayData = rs;
    tree.selectedLeafNodeIds = {};

  }

  selectAllNodes() {
    this.treeComp.treeModel.doForAll((node: TreeNode) => node.setIsSelected(true));
    //  firstNode.setIsSelected(true);

  }

  onTreeLoad(){
    console.log('tree');
  }



  feedData() {

    const results = Object.keys(this.data.info).map(k => ({
      name: k,
      children: this.data.info[k].properties
        ? Object.keys(this.data.info[k].properties).map(kk => ({ name: kk }))
        : []

    }));

    this.nodes = results;





  }

  feedAnother() {



    const results = Object.keys(this.dataa.info).map(k => ({
      name: k,
      children: this.dataa.info[k].properties
        ? Object.keys(this.dataa.info[k].properties).map(kk => ({ name: kk }))
        : []
    }));
    this.nodes = results;


  }

  onActivate(event) {
    this.selectedDataList.push(event.node.data);
    console.log(this.selectedDataList)
  }

  onDeactivate(event) {
    const index = this.selectedDataList.indexOf(event.node.data);
    this.selectedDataList.splice(index, 1);
    console.log(this.selectedDataList)
  }
```

below is my stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hrbppy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just, in your function feed data call to your function this.selectAllNodes() enclosed in a setTimeout. You can see your [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zwzlhc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
setTimeout(()=>{
   this.selectAllNodes()
})
```

NOTE: I see in your code you try to control in diferents ways the items selected. I simplified using a recursive function.

In this.treeComp.treeModel.selectedLeafNodeIds we have the items that are changed, so

```
  getAllChecked()
  {
    const itemsChecked=this.getData(
              this.treeComp.treeModel.selectedLeafNodeIds,null)
    console.log(itemsChecked);
  }

  getData(nodesChanged,nodes) {
    nodes=nodes||this.treeComp.treeModel.nodes
    let data: any[] = []
      nodes.forEach((node: any) => {
        //in nodesChanged we has object like {1200002:true,123132321:false...}
        if (nodesChanged[node.id]) //can be not changed, and then it's null because
                           //it's not in object or can be changed to false
          data.push({id:node.id,name:node.name})
          //or data.push(node.name); //if only need the "name"
          if (node.children)
              data=[...data,...this.getData(nodesChanged,node.children)]
      }
      );
    return data
  }
```

**Updated** I updated the function getData to include the "parent" of the node, but looking the code of @Raghul selvam, his function like me more than mine.

```
getData(nodesChanged,nodes,prefix) {
    nodes=nodes||this.treeComp.treeModel.nodes
    let data: any[] = []
      nodes.forEach((node: any) => {
        if (nodesChanged[node.id])
          data.push(prefix?prefix+"."+node.name:node.name)
          if (node.children)
              data=[...data,...this.getData(nodesChanged,node.children,prefix?prefix+"."+node.name:node.name)]
      }
      );
    return data
  }
```

And call it as

```
this.getData(this.treeComp.treeModel.selectedLeafNodeIds,null,"")
```

Comment: ok but i used the get the selected data in the below format laptop

config.ram

config.processor

config.hdd

link

name

company.model

company.maker

company.country

company.enterprise

Comment: I u`pdated my answer, but the code of @raghulselvam it's ok too. The idea is not use an auxiliar array, it's not necesary

Answer (score 3):

Use [updatedata](https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/events#updatedata) and [initialized](https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/events#initialized) event to update the tree view to check all checkboxes.

**app.component.html**

```html
<tree-root #tree *ngIf ="nodes" [nodes]="nodes" [options]="options" [focused]="true"
    (initialized)="onTreeLoad()"
    (updateData)="updateData()"
    (select)="onActivate($event)"
    (deselect)="onDeactivate($event)">
</tree-root>
```

It'll initiate `tree-root` component only if `nodes` variable is available,
then in the `initialized` and `updateData` event call `selectAllNodes` method to select all checkboxes.

**app.component.ts**

```ts
updateData() {
  this.selectAllNodes();
}

onTreeLoad(){
  this.selectAllNodes();
}
```

Refer to this [slackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jfgt9j) for working example.

Comment: But here the click(tree.treeModel) is not working after updating select all

Comment: this is because we cannot use template variables when the structural directives used in the element, now the code updated to satisfy all functionalities. this might help to solve your problem  refer : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jfgt9j

Answer (score 2):

You could add this in your onTreeLoad function. You could add a boolean flag(treeLoaded) for tracking if the tree has loaded or not.

```
onTreeLoad(tree){

   this.selectAllNodes();
    this.treeLoaded = true;
  }
```

Comment: can u test this with my stackblitz ?